# Query with multiple where clause

Tags: 7, database

I have a query that works fine with one where clause however when I add AND it doesn't work, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$args2 = array(':name' => $existingproductIDfield);
$args3 = array(':vid' => '6');
    $result2 = db_query('SELECT * FROM taxonomy_term_data WHERE name = :name', $args2 .'AND vid = :vid', $args3);

    if ($result2->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($result2 as $row) print_r($row);

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter replacement is done all in one go, and you just need to provide a single associative array of args to `db_query()` for those replacements:

```
$args = array(':name' => $existingproductIDfield, ':vid' => 6);

$result2 = db_query('SELECT * FROM taxonomy_term_data WHERE name = :name AND vid = :vid', $args);
```

Comment: Clive you are the query master! Once again you helped me, thank you very much!

Comment: Hah "query master", I like that! Time to order some new business cards...